# MySQL inner join COUNT optimization

Tags: mysql

```
select COUNT(b.register_no)
from table1 a
         INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.register_no = b.register_no
         INNER JOIN table3 c ON a.register_no = c.register_no
    AND b.card_no = c.card_no;
```

The SQL statement takes 3 minutes to execute,Table1 has 2 million data,Table2 has 2.5 million data,Table3 has 4 million data,

```
explain:
table     type       Extra
tabel2    index      Using where; Using index
table3    ref        Using where
table1    eq_ref     Using index
```

Comment: can try on EXISTS clause. [EXISTS clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
a:  INDEX(register_no)
b:  INDEX(register_no,  card_no)
c:  INDEX(register_no,  card_no)
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Be aware that when `JOINing` a `COUNT` may be inflated.  This is because the `JOIN` occurs before the `COUNT`.  (learning's suggestion about `EXISTS` may give smaller numbers.)

Is there some reason to check that `b.register_no` is `NOT NULL`?  That is what `COUNT(b.register_no)` implies.  Probably `COUNT(*)` is sufficient.

Comment: (The first block is cryptic. This would make useful comments: Do you find it answers the implied *How do I get this inner join COUNT efficiently?*)

Comment: @greybeard - Adding those indexes to the indicated table may speed up the query, thereby making the "join COUNT efficiently".  Or is the "first block" something else?

Comment: *The first block* is the three create-less *index*es alright. And reasons to check for a join criterium not to be NULL should be scarce given INNER JOINs.